# Right approach on login via ajax with Codeigniter REST API

Tags: php, ajax, rest, codeigniter

Hi and thanks you in advance. I am trying to authenticate users via AJAX with POST method and calling the controller "serv_resApp.php". There i have one method login_post() which gets email and password, then goes to private method "checkUser" with the two parameters.
Then goes to db to run the query and return the data, but am not getting what i expect. Any guidance is really appreciated.
PS: I had the checkUser method in models but it wasn't working either so I moved to the controller.

This is my actual code:

/controllers/serv_resApp.php

```
<?php 
  include (APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

  class Serv_resApp extends REST_Controller
  {
     public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
     }



     function login_post()
     {
       // $this->load->model('funciones_model');
       $u = $this->input->post('e'); 
       $p = $this->input->post('p');
       $res = $this->checkUser($u, $p);
       $result = $res;
       print_r($result);
       $this->response($result, 200);
     }

     private function checkUser($u , $p)
     {
       $em = $u;
       $pa = md5($p);
       // $this->db->where('email', $em);
       // $this->db->where('password', $pa);
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$em' AND `password` = $pa;");

     if($query->num_rows() > 0){
         foreach($query->result() as $row){
             $data[] = $row;
         }
         var_dump($query);
         echo "true";
         return $data;
      }else{
           var_dump($query);
           return false;
      }



     }
```

}

```
////// Ajax call
    $.ajax({
  url: "serv_resApp/login",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  cache: false,
  data: {e:'gabriel075@mail.com',
         p:'test'},
  success: function(data){
    if (data==null) {
      alert("data == NULL");
      return false;
    }
    else{
      alert("Exito!!");
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      alert(data);

    }
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("TEXt Error!!!");
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting, and what is currently happening?

Comment: i am expecting a success in the query to put a flag and then return the user id, what is currently happening is getting a error on:
Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in num_rows.

Comment: Just for testing i modify the function to:
public function usr_post()
    {     
        $em =$this->post('e');
        $pa =$this->post('p'); 
        $data = array('returned: '.$em.' '.$pa);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users`;");
        $usuarios = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
           $usuarios[] = $row;
        }
        $this->response($usuarios);
    }
And the query is not working, because i getting this:
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Comment: In general am able to post and get the data inside the REST_Controller, but when am trying to make any query it always return NULL or FALSE

Comment: Please don't just store passwords as MD5s, it's not secure in the least. You should be using per user salted hashes with a stronger hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo or print for debugging in `ajax` served method, instead just log it. If you print then it will be included response.

**Javascript:**

I corrected your post url to `serv_resApp/login_post`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "serv_resApp/login_post",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            e: 'gabriel075@mail.com',
            p: 'test'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                alert("Exito!!");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("TEXt Error!!!");
        }
    });
```

Don't send query response to UI because

**PHP Code:**

```
function login_post() {
    // $this->load->model('funciones_model');
    $u = $this->input->post('e');
    $p = $this->input->post('p');
    $res = null; 
    if($this->checkUser($u, $p)){
           $res = array('code' => 200, 'message' => 'successs');
    }

    echo json_encode($res);
    exit;   
}

private function checkUser($u, $p) {
    $em = $u;
    $pa = md5($p);
    // $this->db->where('email', $em);
    // $this->db->where('password', $pa);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$em' AND `password` = $pa;")->result_array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        //var_dump($query); echo "true"; 
        return $data;
    } else {
        //var_dump($query);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check this [**CI documentation**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: hey really thanks it works nice changes you made, unfortunately the error persist, i haven't figured out yet but i know is in the query inside the checkUser method, if i change the query to "SELECT email FROM `users`" i get more num_rows as expected, but if i try to add any parameters it just doesn't work. I don't see why it happens :/

Comment: yes the query is: ($em) is the email
$sql = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql,$em);
And the response:
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in <b>/home/misgasto/public_html/application/controllers/serv_resApp.php</b> on line <b>107</b><br />
I know for sure that the field email exist in db

Comment: check the edited query `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$em' AND password = $pa;")->result_array();`. I added `->result_array()` at end.

Comment: I run the query:
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$em' AND password = $pa;")->result_array();

The response was:
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Comment: Are you auto loading `database`? If not add this line `$this->load->database();` in `checkUser()` before using `$this->db->`.

Comment: Yes, in config/autoload i have the database selected, either way i try what you said of: $this->load->database(); and i get the same error:
Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object
One thing i have noticed is when i do this:
echo $em." ".$pa." ".$u." ".$p;
and then test ajax from the ajax in browser and chrome extension i get different echo's in firefox firebug i can see the four variables and in chrome extension i can only see a different password.

Comment: Please check the edit to `foreach ($query as $row)`. May be you are using `foreach ($query->result() as $row)` in `checkUser()`.

Comment: After edit:
private function checkUser($u, $p) {
    $this->load->database();
    $em = $u;
    $pa = md5($p);
    echo $em." ".$pa." ".$u." ".$p;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$em' AND password = $pa;")->result_array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
The response was:
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Comment: Am testing some ajax calls from firebug, and inspect element from chrome and when i make a test from apigee or any other api test, i gets this:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Resource id #32
    [2] => Resource id #38
    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
        )

    [6] => 0
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 
)
{"code":200,"message":"successs"}